# Embedding a Radar (from Google) in app

Tags: android, package

I want to implement a radar in my app.  It's basically an app where it will put a dot of the desired location on the radar based on the user's current location so the user can navigate towards the dot, kind of like the radars in FPS games.

I found this: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git%2FRadar

The thing is, it seems that the only way (the way I know) to utilize this is to install it as a separate app and have to main app call the activities in Radar app.  Meaning, there will be two projects and two apps will be installed on the user's device.

I tried joining the two projects together, and have two packages in one project.  The problem is, the R.java file for the Radar app won't generate in its own package.  I have looked through the posts in this forum and it seems that no one has tried to embed this radar into their apps yet.

I have tried messing with the AndroidManifest file but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I created a project 'Radar' in eclipse and set it (via properties->android->set as library project) to be a library project. Then from the link specified in the first tread above, I created and copy/pasted all the java code, drawables, String.xml and the AndroidManifest.xml to the corresponding location in my library project. Then I went to my 'main' project and set (via properties->android->library add library) the 'radar' project to be an imported library.
From there on I could easily create an intent in my main project which calls RadarActivity and passes 2 float values as the destination coordinates. It works well and shows the radar in a view when pressing the button that triggers that intent.

I have a button in my 'main' project and it launches the RadarActivity as follows:

```
findViewById(R.id.btShowRadar).setOnClickListener(
    new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CarLocatorActivity.this, com.google.android.radar.RadarActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", (float)getCarLattitude());
            intent.putExtra("longitude", (float)getCarLongitude());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: i'm currently trying to test the radar intent ,did you get it to work at the end ? because the radar doesn't seem to update the distance eventhough my gps is activated , maybe i have to change my location ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to use the Radar view in your own project. If youre using Eclipse then I  would create a library project from the Google code as described here : 
 http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html

and then refer to that from your own project (also described on that link).

The R file is created automatically as descrbed [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#overview_resources) and also [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html). Quote :

> Caution: You should never modify the R.java file by hand—it is generated by the aapt tool when your project is compiled. Any changes are overridden next time you compile.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did and it does work.  But I was wondering if there was a way to embed the Radar project into my own project, so that I wouldn't need to have two projects.  I have tried putting them together and have multiple packages in one project, but the R.java file for the Radar project does not generate.

Comment: Why would you not want to have two projects? If you really want the source code in your project why not just copy the source code over to the source folder?

Comment: For deployment reasons, wouldn't it be ideal to have just one project?  I never deployed a project before but looking at the various guides, it seems that most apps are deployed per one project.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was pretty simple, a bit too simple that it didn't even occur to me initially.  Just simply copy and paste the R file from the original Radar project!

Comment: You wouldn't have two projects for deployment. If you created the Google Radar project as a library project then your own would simply use it as a library. Not so sure you should be copying the 'R' file as this is automatically generated by Eclipse - see the additonal info and link I have given above.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to integrate a radar on android is using [android radar library](https://github.com/karamsa/android-radar).